# Parse HttpErrorResponse Value to JSON Object

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I have the following `HttpErrorResponse`

[image]

I need to get the status and message from the `value` property by parsing the JSON object

I have tried the following

```
this.http.request(uploadReq).subscribe(event => {
      if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress)
        this.progress = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);
      if (this.progress == 100) {
        this.uploadeda = true;
        this.error = false;
      }
      else if (event.type === HttpEventType.Response)
        this.message = event.body.toString();

    }, err => { console.error(JSON.parse(err.value.toString()).status);});
```

I keep getting the following error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Comment: Look at the screenshot - `err.error.value`, and why `toString` *then* `JSON.parse` it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to parse the error response. Also, the value is inside the error object. So err.error.value will give you the expected